# SE app drains battery on LG G3 Android 5.0

Tags: support, android-app

My Avast battery saver application keeps suggesting I shut down the SE app. It indicates that it uses 10 times the battery my second most energy-consumming app uses.

Any fix or explanations?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Avast Battery Saver]
[image: IMG: Over the last week : In red is background use, and green shows active use. Process time used is 1 hour.]

Comment: How did you analyze the issue is SE? Any data you want to share? How did you use that app in the meantime?

Comment: Does that arrow next to 'Stack Exchange 12%' gives any specific details? If yes, consider adding it.

Comment: I added a second screenshot. Avast is in French, but I offered a translation for most of the items in the image description.

Comment: Probably late, but have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app to make it run clean as new? While I've mentioned that I don't have this issue, I'm really curious as why you have it. The possible causes are usually related to synchronization failure, hogging the resource and thus draining battery... Were you using many SE widgets? Did you receive push notifications from SE app?

Comment: Yes I have push notification. I Will try to reinstall.

Comment: Reinstalling did not fix the issue.

Comment: What does your phone's internal battery usage graph indicate? Avast could be wrong. For what it's worth, even with fairly heavy usage, the SE app doesn't make it into my top 10 battery drainers.

Comment: Rather than uninstalling/reinstalling, have you tried force stopping and clearing the data and cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you restrict background data usage for this app? That way SE won't run except when you open it. It might work.

You can do it this way:

- Open *Settings*
- Go to *Data Usage*
- Look for the Stack Exchange App
- Toggle "Restrict app background data" to disable background data on cellular networks

Comment: I did this. Will get back to you with the results.