# Stack Exchange app is draining battery

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app

I can't really provide much except to say that using the app, it's used over 30% of my battery in ~40 minutes.

[image: Stack Exchange using over 40% of battery in less than 24 hours]

Will the developers be kind enough to develop the app in a more energy-efficient way? This is overkill for a Q&A site app.

Comment: That doesn't look too battery intensive, it's a bit higher than I see but nothing substantial. It's still using proportionally less than Safari for example.

Comment: Similar report about android app: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267591/se-app-drains-battery-on-lg-g3-android-5-0.

Answer (score 9):

> it's used over 30% of my battery in ~40 minutes

No, it says you have used 38% of your battery on 1.5 hours browsing. That is not much more than Safari, which would be using 30% when it reaches for 1.5 hours too, based on its current rate in your screenshot.

Given that the SE app is actually nothing more than a browser (I even think they have used the web view multiple times), I don't find it strange it uses at least the amount of battery Safari uses.

Comment: Furthermore, it's actually used 33% if the device hasn't been charged in the middle of the 24h period, since the percentages shown are percentages of the consumption of the battery rather than the raw battery percentage figure. Given there's 12% battery left, (100-12)×0.38≈33.

Comment: I am not sure how that number is calculated, but either way, the comparison to Safari will remain the same, which tells there is not so much to improve.

Comment: Just nitpicking but the app is only a browser in the sense of "you browse Q&As"... it's a bit more than a browser in terms of actual web browsers (i.e. what is generally known as "a browser")

Comment: The controls are from the built-in web view, so it also has the performance and battery drainage of the browser controls. @Cai

Comment: I'm pretty certain nothing other than post content is in a webview

Comment: So you have the `skeleton + web view`, which means `battery drainage = skeleton battery drainage + web view battery drainage`.